# Why does nullable KeyValuePair<,> have no key property?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-2.0

I have the following:

```
KeyValuePair<string, string>? myKVP;
// code that may conditionally do something with it
string keyString = myKVP.Key;  
// throws 'System.Nullable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>' 
// does not contain a definition for 'Key'
```

I'm sure there is some reason for this as I can see that the type is nullable. Is it because I am trying to access the key when `null` could cause bad things to happen?

Comment: It doesn't throw, you get a compile error.

Comment: It can be cast to the KeyValuePair if you want to directly access that property. Or you can use myKVP.Value.Key as others have pointed out. Compile errors no matter what though because in your example you have not assigned anything to myKVP so it's always null and the compiler catches that for you

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
myKVP.Value.Key;
```

Here is a stripped down version of `System.Nullable<T>`:

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T: struct
{
    public T Value { get; }
}
```

Since the `Value` property is of type `T` you must use the `Value` property to get at the wrapped type instance that you are working with.

**Edit:** I would suggest that you check the `HasValue` property of your nullable type prior to using the `Value`.

```
if (myKVP.HasValue)
{
    // use myKVP.Value in here safely
}
```

Comment: It is a bit weird at first glance but once you understand how it works under the covers it makes perfect sense. :)

Comment: so i guess, the nullable has a value and that in this case the value (if it exists) is a KeyValuePair. so in this case myKVP is a nullable and its value property IS the KeyValuePair ?

Comment: Exactly!  Your previous comment is 100% correct and a good way to look at it.

Comment: I actually second that this doesn't make sense - it's perfectly *logical*, but not sensible. It's pretty damned ugly in fact.

Comment: You can avoid calling .Value, .HasValue, or .GetValueOrDefault() if you supply a default value for nulls using the ?? operator. For example: KeyValuePair<string,string> foo = myNullable ?? someDefault;

Comment: Or, in more current versions of C#, myKVP?.Value

Answer (score 1):

This is because nullable types can be assigned null value or the actual value, hence you have to call ".value" on all nullable types. ".value" will return the underlying value or throw a System::InvalidOperationException.

You can also call ".HasValue" on nullable type to make sure that there is value assigned to the actual type.